# Is this possible to apply bucketisation in Spring Boot (TOMCAT)

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, threadpool

I exposed 2 api's

***/endpoint/A***  and ***/endpoint/B***  .

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint/A")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseA> controllerA() throws InterruptedException {

        ResponseA responseA = serviceA.responseClient();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseA);
    }



@GetMapping("/endpoint/B")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseA> controllerB() throws InterruptedException {

        ResponseA responseB = serviceB.responseClient();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseB);
    }
```

Services implemented regarding endpoint A internally call ***/endpoint/C***   and endpoint B internally call ***/endpoint/D***.

As external service ***/endpoint/D*** taking more time i.e getting response from ***/endpoint/A*** takes more time hence whole threads are stucked that is affecting  ***/endpoint/B***.
I tried to solve this using executor service having following implementation

```
@Bean(name = "serviceAExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor serviceAExecutor(){

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(120);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        taskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(120);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("serviceAExecutor");
        return taskExecutor;
    }
```

Even after implementing this if I received more than 200 request on ***/endpoint/A*** simultaneously (greater than default max number of threads in Tomcat server) then I am not getting responses from ***/endpoint/B*** as all threads are busy for getting response from endpoint A or in queue.

Can someone plz suggest  is there any way to apply bucketization on each exposed endpoint level and allow only limited request to process at a time & put remaining into bucket/queue so that request on other endpoints can work properly ?

Edit:-  following is solution approach

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint/A")
        public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseA>> controllerA() throws InterruptedException {
    
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->controllerHelperA());
        }



    @GetMapping("/endpoint/B")
        public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseB>> controllerB() throws InterruptedException {
    
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->controllerHelperB());
        }

private ResponseEntity<ResponseA> controllerHelperA(){

        ResponseA responseA = serviceA.responseClient();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseA);
    }

private ResponseEntity<ResponseB> controllerHelperB(){

        ResponseB responseB = serviceB.responseClient();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseB);
    }
```

Comment: Utilize the async servlet api. Which will free the request handling thread upon needing to return a response. Also adding the executor doesn't doe anything unless you are using `@Async` on that method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I put Async on the method  that is handling the request and change  the return type to CompletableFuture as well even then my problem isn't resolved

Comment: You don't need the `@Async` part. What you need to do is configure the  task executor used by the web to include more threads. Also returning `CompetableFuture` should be enough for the async servlet API to kick in. If you however only implement this partially in your application this will only help a little as the other stuff is still blocking the request handling as before.

Comment: @M.Deinum. by fully implementing **CompletableFuture** , you mean use CompletableFuture as return type in each and every intermediary functions that are in b/w endpoint A and external service ?

Comment: No the controller needs to return the completable future how you create it doesn't matter, you could wrap sync.blocking code with it. The importance is the return type of the controller not the services. But if yu have 200 endpoints and only 1 is using the async API it won't get much benefit. Bu tit might work enough if you tune the `spring.task.` properties with enough threads.

Comment: @M.Deinum it seems that putting CompletableFuture at controller level is working , just have one doubt that would I need to define a bean to configure ThreadPoolExecutor and put Async annotation over controller so that  threads used by CompletableFuture are from configured ThreadPoolExecutor ?

Comment: No. There is already one configured and adding `@Async` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum but how it get to know that which executor it has to use until or unless I don't put any Async(value = <name of executor>) over controller ?
As far as I know it gonna use ForkJoinPool if don't assigned any .

I edited my question, attached how I used ComplatableFuture for solving this issue

Comment: It doesn't your understanding is wrong. Spring Boot pre-configures a TaskExecutor and when using the async servlet API this one will be detected and used. You can control this one by setting the `spring.task` settings in your `application.properties`. Return a `Callable` instead of a `CompletableFUture` Spring will handle it correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I replaced CompletableFuture with Callable & try to do perform testing with around 2k parallel request,  it is giving me error **Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached**


also Callable seems blocking to me as if I use callable , initial problem again pops up

Comment: Callable will be wrapped in a defferedresult. Which Spring Boot version are you using, I was assuming the latest **but** the fact that a new thread needs to be created seems to imply you aren't. Ah, wait you added your own thread pool, which backs off the auto config, leading to the web using the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which will create a new thread for each. You should either ditch your custom thread pool, or configure the web to use that one (you can configure it through an `WebConfigurer` and by implementation the `configureAsync` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum got your point it's working.
I saw few implementations where CompletableFuture is used instead of callable with DefferedResult. so which implementation is better one  ?

Comment: Doesn't matter in the end they do the same, you are probably better of with a `Callable` in this case. The `CompleteableFuture` is nice to return from async method calls. The `DeferredResult` will tie your code more to Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC supports the async servlet API introduced in Servlet API 3.0. To make it easier when your controller returns a `Callable`, `CompletableFuture` or `DeferredResult` it will run in a background thread and free the request handling thread for further processing.

```java
@GetMapping("/endpoint/A")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseA>> controllerA() throws InterruptedException {
  return () {
    return controllerHelperA();
  }
}

private ResponseEntity<ResponseA> controllerHelperA(){

  ResponseA responseA = serviceA.responseClient();
  return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseA);
}
```

Now this will be executed in a background thread. Depending on your version of Spring Boot and if you have configured your own `TaskExecutor` it will either

1. use the `SimpleAsycnTaskExecutor` (which will issue a warning in your logs),
2. the default provided `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which is configurable through the `spring.task.execution` namespace
3. Use your own `TaskExecutor` but requires additional configuration.

If you don't have a custom `TaskExecutor` defined and are on a relatively recent version of Spring Boot 2.1 or up (IIRC) you can use the following properties to configure the `TaskExecutor`.

```
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=20
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size=120
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity=50
spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive=120s
spring.task.execution.thread-name-prefix=async-web-thread
```

Generally this will be used to execute Spring MVC tasks in the background as well as regular `@Async` tasks.

If you want to explicitly configure which `TaskExecutor` to use for your web processing you can create a `WebMvcConfigurer` and implement the `configureAsyncSupport` method.

```java
@Configuration
public class AsyncWebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  private final AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

  public AsyncWebConfigurer(AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    this.taskExecutor=taskExecutor;
  }

  public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
  }
}
```

You could use an `@Qualifier` on the constructor argument to specify which `TaskExecutor` you want to use.